# Haskell: how to compare tuples?

Tags: list, haskell, compare, lookup, tuples

I'm trying to make a tuple list store some information in a particular way. Such as `scotland` belongs to `uk`, `england` belongs to `uk`, etc. Then take two strings as arguments (`String -> String -> Bool`) to make something like:

```
Main> owns "china" "beijing"
True
Main> owns "uk" "beijing"
False
```

Here's my code:

```
lst = [("uk","scotland"),("uk","england"),("uk","wales"),("china","beijing"),("china","hongkong"),("china","shanghai")]

owns :: String -> String -> Bool
owns a b = [n|(a,b) <- lst, (n == a)] && [m|(a,b) <- lst, (m==b]
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 6):

If I understood your question right, you build a table of relations. Then, you get a single relation and want to check, whether it is in this table? Just use `elem`. `elem a b` yields true, if and only if `a` is in b.

Comment: Example: elem ("china","beijing") lst

Comment: Idiomatically: ``("china","beijing") `elem` lst``.

Answer (score 2):

Look for "association lists" in the Haskell list library, and the `lookup` function:

```
Prelude> lookup "china" ls
Just "beijing"
```

where `lookup` is implemented as:

```
lookup _key []          =  Nothing
lookup  key ((x,y):xys)
    | key == x          =  Just y
    | otherwise         =  lookup key xys
```

Once you can lookup an element via its key, you can then compare that against the expected value.

Comment: @user notice `lookup` only returns the first match, so this won't work for your needs.  FUZxxl has a good solution of simply constructing a tuple and using `elem` as the query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a definition for the `owns` function:

```
owns :: String -> String -> Bool
owns a b = (a,b) `elem` lst
```

To answer the title of your question, any two tuples of the same length can be compared if their elements can be compared. If you are familiar with type classes at this point,

```
(Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a, b)
(Eq a, Eq b, Eq c) => Eq (a, b, c)
...
```