# haskell, how to make a small database by using tuple

Tags: list, haskell, compare, tuples, vlookup

here s my question, i need to construct a database representing information about one country owning county owning city, using a list of 2-tuples (i.e., pairs)
for example c1 owns c2, which owns c3, which owns c4, but where the "indirect" ownership of c4 by c1 (etc.) is not directly stated.
i need to write a function 'owns' which, given two strings naming country returns a Boolean indicating whether the first owns the second (even indirectly, as with the case of c1 and c4 above).
here s my code, and i know it s not quite right, i new very new to haskell ....therefore, need help please....

```
lst = [("uk","scotland"),("scotland","aberdeen"),("china","hongkong"),("hongkong","kulong")]
owns :: String-> String -> Bool
owns a b 
    | n = lookup a (fromList lst)
        |if b==n 
            return true
        |otherwise m = lookup n (fromlist lst)
            if b==m
            return true
    | otherwise = False
```

i m expecting the output result should be something like:

```
Main> owns "uk" "scotland"
True
Main> owns "uk" "aberdeen"
True
Main> owns "uk" "hongkong"
False
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [haskell, how to compare tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654850/haskell-how-to-compare-tuples)

Comment: `return` doesn't do what you think it does: It is not used to return a value from a function, but to wrap a single value (often a "result" of a former calculation, hence the name) in a monadic context (e.g. `do` notation).

Comment: well at least you changed the question on this one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
owns parent child = parent == child || any (owns parent) [p | (p, c) <- lst, c == child]
```

You will want to know how this works.

First, we recognise that this is a recursion question. c1 owns c2 owns c3 owns c4 etc. We don't know how many steps this could take. So we need a base case and a recursive case.

The base case is `parent == child`. If this is True, then the overall answer is True.

Now, the recursive case. `any` takes a function and a list, and returns True if any member of the list makes the function return True.

*(I need to sleep now, will come back to this later if needed.)*